# finding all the values of $x$ in $\cos^{-1}\big(\cos(2x^2)\big)=x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $$\cos^{-1}\big(\cos(2x^2)\big)=x$$ for all the values of $x$.
I really do not know where to start nor end can some one please help me.

Comment: There's no equation. What is it you need to solve?

Comment: sorry Henrik it has been corrected.

Answer (score 5):

$x\in[0,\pi]$ because that is the range of arccosine.

Then you have $\cos x = \cos 2x^2$, so $x=\pm2x^2+2\pi k$.  Solve the quadratic equations.

Answer (score 0):

Note that :
$
\cos^{-1} y =x 
$
means that 
$
\cos x= y
$
so your equation become
$$
\cos x= \cos (2x^2) 
$$
tah you can solve noting that it must be:
$ x=2x^2 +2k\pi$ or $ x=-2x^2 +2k\pi$

Oops !  I was anticipated .....